# moving buttons down the screen

Tags: android, eclipse

im a complete noob when it comes to eclipse and coding, , then started on the eclipse side, ive managed to get the app working, and doing what i want, but im having great problem moving my buttons down the front screen, ie image at the top, and the 3 rows of 3 buttons beneath the image, the buttons are centered in the screen,  please be gentle with me lol i know your all code heads, which im not, if you could  please point me to where the values are, and what to put, that would be great. i have meddled around with the code in both the .java and.xml files, heres my code from the xml, i have changed all the values, 1 at a time to see the result, while this has helped with positioning the buttons right and left, and the spacing in the middle, i cant get the buttons to move down ,

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/containerView"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"    
android:padding="0dip"
android:layout_margin="0dip"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/verticalScrollView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/containerViewHorizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"    
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">        

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/containerViewHorizontalBottom"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"    
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/containerHorizontalButtons"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"    
                        android:padding="0dip"
                        android:layout_margin="0dip"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </LinearLayout>

                </HorizontalScrollView> 

            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What have You tried? Could You share some image of what are You trying to achieve?

Comment: hi heres screenshot, im trying to move the buttons down, below the image, i can adapt the image, and change size of buttons and where they are relative to the screen, but i cant find how to just move them down   https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kfc5p4exb4cedm/device-2013-10-31-100749.png

Answer (score 0):

try android docs for the basics

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: looked in there thanks, didnt help, lots of info everywhere on how to set the page up, but my page is already set up, i just need to move the buttons down :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` as parent layout.

To move `Any Element` to bottom of the screen `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
To center `Any Element` `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Comment: hi i dont want all the screens to follow the rule, just the one above, ive changed all the values, but nothing moves the buttons down :)